# PHP SDK-How to know whether or not person from Facebook has installed and authorized my app on Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've been keeping track of all my users on server side of my app(storing their Facebook Ids (within scope of my app of course)), but since I can find Facebook id from anyone using Facebook with this site : http://findmyfbid.com/, again of course those ids are not within my app scope, I can fetch their basic, publicly available info, like id, name etc. But I need a way to know if user has installed my app or not. Only way that I found that Facebook informs me that users did not install my app is if I try to send them notification. Then I get this response from Graph:

> Graph returned an error: (#200) Cannot send notifications to a user who has not installed the app
>   Graph returned an error: 403

Is there any other way to find out if user has authorized and installed my app aside from calling post method and sending notification?

Comment: see my answer. it would be easier to answer if you would present a use case though, why would you want to know if a specific user authorized your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That ID you get from findmyfbid.com is the "global/real" ID, you should never need/use that one and you should actually not even get it in any way. That page is scraping the profiles, which is not allowed on Facebook. After authorization, you get an "App Scoped ID", you need to use that one.

Anyway, you can just store all authorized users in a database right after they authorized your App (Because you know when they do that). And there is a "deauthorization callback" in the App Settings if you want to know is someone deauthorized your App - you can (and should) remove that user from your database then.

Comment: Hey, thanks for fast answer. Another question please, do you know if I could get those deauthorized users through Graph API call?

Comment: no, you would have to store them on your own. there is no api to get "all authorized users".